# Terminal doesn't close after process kill

Tags: bash, spring-boot

I run a Spring Boot app with the following command,

```
java -jar myapp-1.0.0.jar & echo $! > "myapp.pid"
```

and killing the process with the following command

```
kill `cat "myapp.pid"` or kill -9 `cat "myapp.pid"`
```

and when I checked process is killed but terminal doesn't return, it becomes hanged. When I press a key, it returns normal. What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 1):

As you are running it in background and executing one more command `echo` it is not coming back to `$` prompt actually. Just try like below it will work:-

```
  java -jar myapp-1.0.0.jar
```

And kill the process from different terminal

```
 kill `cat "myapp.pid"` or kill -9 `cat "myapp.pid"`
```

Comment: so where you save myapp.pid in first step?

Comment: You can still `java -jar myapp-1.0.0.jar & echo $! > "myapp.pid"` so after the killing even if the prompt does not reflect or come back to `$` prompt you don't need to worry about it. Just press any key or enter key it will return. This will not create any issue.